# Simple SharePoint Flow to Send Email Issues

Tags: flow, choice-field

I am at a loss of 4+ hours trying to understand why this flow will not work. I have SharePoint Library with a Yes/No choice column for whether a file Needs Updating that I want to trigger an email. Everything I try either results in the condition being false which it shouldn't be or the flow failing. Here is my latest code that fails. Originally I wasn't using the value version of the field and the flow would run but result in a false condition even when the Needs Updating field was set to Yes. I also was using is equal to Yes, but then I read another thread that suggested you should use the expression true. I'm unsure of what to do/try next. This should have been a 10 minute job. It has to be something silly that I am missing.

I am using NeedsUpdating Value as condition field.[image]
[image: SharePointChoiceField]

Another pic after changed from True to Yes
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your condition assumes that the`NeesUpdating` field is a yes/no field. However, `NeesUpdating` field is simply a text/choice field. So you can't compare text to the boolean values (`true` and `false`).

So, to fix the issue, simply update your Condition to compare with `Yes` like on the screenshot below:

[image]

> Remember, you don't need any quotes or formula, you simply need to type `Yes` in the condition.

Comment: I did try using Yes however it comes back that the expression result is false. Even though I chose Yes for that field's metadata.

Comment: I added another pic so you could see the change to Yes and what field it is being based off of.

Comment: It might be that the Yes option has an extra space at the end. But you can debug this issue. Create a new Flow action called Compose and simply add the NeedsUpdating value to it. Then run the FLow. Then, in the debug mode, click on the compose action and carefully look at what value is shown there. There must be some kind of a difference. an extraspace or such like.

Comment: Thank you for that great action! It is indeed coming back with Yes, however when I use the NeedsUpdating Value in the condition the flow fails at the condition. I'm going to delete the field and start over now that you have confirmed that it should work and be as simple as I had thought. I'll update this thread once I redo and test. Thanks so much for getting me this far.

Comment: Re-created the entire scenario and it seems that the issue was with the Send an Email choice I made. Not clear why that would affect the condition and make it fail, but once I changed from Send and Email with Options to just Send an Email. It succeeds/works as intended. @denismolodtsov I marked your response as the answer as it did help me understand the flow software better. Thank YOU!